# Tenho um fragmento que renderiza um xml mas caso não há nenhum registro eu quero que ele renderize uma outra página(xml)

Tags: java, android

Eu sou nova no android e não sei fazer isso. Segue um pequeno pedaço do meu código. Vou verificar se não há registros caso a lista não esteja vazia. Se estiver vazia eu preciso que ele renderize a outra página de sem registros. Como posso fazer isso?

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noa_cidadao2, container, false);
...
        return view; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // Verificar se ha dados ou nao
           boolean isEmpty = false;

            View view = null;

            if( isEmpty ){
                 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noa_cidadao2, container, false);
             }else{
                 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outra, container, false);
            }


            return view; 
    }
```

**EDIT**

Outra forma é trazer o conteúdo dos dois em um único `layout`  e mostrar conforme a quantidade de itens:

Exemplo:

**Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- SETADO A VISIBILIDADE PARA GONE -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listaVazia"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaItens"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
private LinearLayout listaVazia;
private ListView listaItens;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       /** 
        * Inicializamos todos os componentes!
        **/

        listaItens = ListView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.lista));
        listaVazia = LinearLayout.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.lisyVazia));

}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Aqui você deverá saber se existem  itens para ser exibidos!
    if(isEmpty){
        // Se está vazia, vamos esconder a lista de Itens e exibir Lista Vazia!
        listaItens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listaVazia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        listaItens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listaVazia.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hummm Só isso?...

Comment: Vou tentar sim amigo!

Comment: esses dados vem de uma webservice e verifico se a lista esta vazia

Comment: aiiiii não sei se vai dar certo desse jeito...pq eu preciso do view para pegar referencias dos componentes...

Comment: Espera....ta compilando aqui

Comment: CONSEGUI!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Só pegue as referencias se houver algo na lista